# Dropbox api v2 sdk for ruby

Tags: ruby, dropbox, dropbox-api

Has anyone came across Dropbox migration from API v1 to v2?

I could not find `ruby-sdk` for `v2` in official documentation. If I want to migrate from `v1` to `v2`, Should I manually do all the changes in existing `ruby-sdk` for `v1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, Dropbox does not offer an official Ruby SDK for Dropbox API v2.

You'd either need to modify the SDK/library you're using, or implement your app using the [HTTP endpoints](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation) directly.

There's a migration guide here:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/migration-guide

Comment: Thanks @Greg. Any plans to introduce SDK for ruby in near future? Also, It seems API v2 only uses OAuth2 which requires to set redirect URL to be set. But our application uses OAuth1 and redirect url can be localhost or IP of the machine which keeps on changing. Hence preventing us to use OAuth2.  In such case, how can we migrate to V2 ?

Comment: I don't have any news on a potential Ruby SDK for Dropbox API v2. API v2 does only support OAuth 2. If you don't have a stable redirect URI to use, you can use the "code" flow without a redirect URI at all.

Comment: The /oauth2/authorize documentation has information on the code flow here: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#oauth2-authorize Also, this blog post may be helpful: https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2013/07/using-oauth-2-0-with-the-core-api/

Comment: Thanks Greg for you help

Answer (score 4):

I've just published a small library that aims to fill this gap: https://rubygems.org/gems/dropbox_api

Many endpoints are pending and documentation needs to be improved, but it's the best you'll find right now.

I hope it helps you.

Comment: I only saw it a few days ago. We seem to be doing the same thing so we should get in touch.